# How to make my cloud run service public (Allow unauthenticated invocations) using googleapi node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-run

My script deploys a cloud run service, but after several hours of search i can't find the option to make the service public available.

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: 'path/to/keyfile.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
});
const authClient = await auth.getClient();

const run = google.run({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: authClient,
    rootUrl: 'https://europe-west6-run.googleapis.com/'
});


const response = await run.namespaces.services.create({
    parent: 'namespaces/pace21',
    requestBody: {
        metadata: {
            name: 'my-new-service',
            namespace: 'myProject',
            annotations: {
                'run.googleapis.com/ingress': 'all',
            },
        },
        kind: 'Service',
        apiVersion: 'serving.knative.dev/v1',
        spec: {
            template: {
                spec: {
                    containers: [
                        {
                            image: 'europe-west6-docker.pkg.dev/path/to/image',
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            traffic: [{ percent: 100, latestRevision: true }]
        }
    }
}, {})
```

I can see an option in the [package](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/src/apis/run/v1.ts#L186) but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Use the **SetIamPolicy** method after creating the service. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.services/setIamPolicy and https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/run/v1/Overview#setiampolicyrequest The bindings: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/run/v1/Overview#Policy The member is **allUsers** and the role is **roles/run.invoker**.

Comment: Agree with @JohnHanley, it's another API call. One call to deploy the service, another one to manage the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @JohnHanley.

The second request to change the policy of the new service is the answer I was searching for. For completion the node script:

```
const policy_response = await run.projects.locations.services.setIamPolicy({
        resource: `projects/${project_id}/locations/europe-west6/services/${service_name}`,
        requestBody: {
            policy: {
                bindings: [
                    {
                        role: 'roles/run.invoker',
                        members: [
                            'allUsers',
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    });
```